# how to detect the third line before certain line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file, like this:

```
<prop type="ltattr-match">1-1</prop>
id =>3</prop>
<tuv xml:lang="en">
<seg> He is not a good man </seg>
```

And what I want is to detect the third line before the line  He is not a good man , i.e (id =>3). The file is big. what I can do

Comment: The THIRD line before it or the SECOND line before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("mybigfile.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith("<seg>"):
        line_to_detect = lines[idx-3]
        #use idx-2 if you want the _second_ line before this one, 
        #ex `id =>3</prop>`
        print "This line was detected:"
        print line_to_detect
```

Result:

```
This line was detected:
<prop type="ltattr-match">1-1</prop>
```

As we [previously discussed in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16074823#16074823), this method can be memory intensive for very large files. But 100 pages isn't *very* large, so this should be fine.

Comment: Where did you get the "100 pages" from?

Comment: From chat, [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16074775#16074775) specifically.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a [double ended queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with a maximum length: this way, only the required amount of "backlog" is stored and you don't have to fiddle around with slices manually. We don't need the "double-ended-ness", but the normal `Queue` class blocks if the queue is full.

```
import collections
dq = collections.deque([], 3)        # create an empty queue

with open("mybigfile.txt") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line.startswith('<seg>'):
            return dq[0]             # or add to list
        dq.append(line)              # save the line, if already 3 lines stored,
                                     # discard oldest line.
```

Answer (score 1):

Read each line in sequence, remembering only the last 3 read at any point.

Something like:

```
# Assume f is a file object open to your file
last3 = []
last3.append( f.readline() )
last3.append( f.readline() )
last3.append( f.readline() )
while ( True ):
    line = f.readline()
    if (line satisfies condition):
        break
    last3 = last3[1:]+[line]
# At this point last3[0] is 3 lines before the matching line
```

You'll need to modify this to handle files w/ < 3 lines, or if no line matches your condition.

Comment: Scott Hunter@ Can you please formulate this in a code?

Answer (score 0):

```
file = "path/to/the/file"
f = open(file, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
i = 0
for line in lines:
    if "<seg> He is not a good man </seg>" in line:
       print(lines[i]) #Print the prvious line
    else
        i += 1
```

If you need the second line before just change to `print(lines[i-1])`

Comment: This will have `line` be empty.  It certainly won't be the third line, much less "the third line before the line He is not a good man".

Comment: And OP isn't looking for the 3rd line, but the 3rd line BEFORE one with specific content.

Comment: @DSM I thought that you don't need to use the variable you loop.Now it will check the next line and find if it happens more than once.